# Как правильно написать @NamedQuery запрос?

Tags: java, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Не получается правильно написать `@NamedQuery` запрос.
Есть класс `Person`, он содержит поле `Set<'PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers`, которое сохраняется в отдельную таблицу. Необходимо реализовать поиск Person по номеру телефона. Для этого использую `@NameQuery` запрос, но он не работает (исключения тоже нет). Как правильно написать `@NameQuery` запрос или как по другому реализовать поиск Person по номеру телефона?

**Класс `Person`:**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByPhone",
        query = "select p from Person p inner join com.example.sweater.domain.PhoneNumber as pn on  p.id = :pn.person_id")
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"lastName", "firstName", "patronymic"})
})
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    private String patronymic;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_phone_numbers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "person_addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine1", column = @Column(name = "house_number")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine2", column = @Column(name = "street"))
    })
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String lastName, String firstName, String patronymic,
                  Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers, Set<Address> addresses) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
        this.addresses = addresses;

    }
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class PhoneNumber {

    @Size(max = 30)
    private String type;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String number;

    public PhoneNumber() {
    }

    public PhoneNumber(@Size(max = 30) String type, @NotNull @Size(max = 10) String number) {
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
    }
```

---

**Репозиторий:**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
        List<Person> findByPhone(@Param("number") String number);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно таким образом:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByPhoneNumber",
    query = "select p from Person as p join p.phoneNumbers as pn where pn.number = :number")
```

Для более детального изучения см [руководство по JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html).

Comment: спасибо, решение помогло!